# Error in pip: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Tags: 14.04, python, pip

I'm trying install the requests, but I can't do that. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

I tried to install using

```
$ sudo pip install requests
```

and I get the following error

```
Collecting requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 597, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 195, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

My python version is the 2.7
and the pip is 8.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed that problem on my own. I just reinstalled the pip.

First of all I uninstalled the pip

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

after that I just reinstalled the pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install requests
```

and it works.

Comment: This seems a bit intense. Maybe just `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip` would have worked

Comment: i tried but I didn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

fixed it temporary:

```
pip install requests -i http://a.b.com/pypi/simple --trusted-host a.b.com
```

fixed it permanent:

linux OS: add these in ~/.pip/pip.conf(create it if no exist)

```
[global]
index-url = http://a.b.com/pypi/simple
[install]
trusted-host = a.b.com
```

ps: `http://a.b.com/pypi/simple` your proxy_http_address